# Back button on question view does not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Sometimes it's greyed out, sometimes it registers a press but does not respond. Sometimes minimising the app and returning resolves the issue, but generally the fastest solution is to manually close and reopen the app.

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.2.1 (Build 13D20)